Session change in php not caught in while loop
Trying to implement Server Side Events - On the server side (php), the below while loop doesn't catch when the session is changed from another php script. It does catch it when the whole web page is reloaded. The second code without the loop catches the session change. Any clues to why and how to handle?
Not working code
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
    
function sendEvent($event, $data) {
    echo "event: $event\n";
    echo "data: $data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

// Check signing status and send events
while (true) {
    session_start();  // Reopen the session to get the latest data
    $status = $_SESSION['signing_status'];
    session_write_close(); // Immediately close the session to avoid locks
    
    sendEvent("event",$status);
    // Wait for a few seconds before checking again
    sleep(4);
}

?>

Working code
<?php
session_start();
$status = $_SESSION['signing_status'];
session_write_close();

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

$eventId = 0;  // Initialize event ID

sendEvent("event", $_SESSION['signing_status']);

function sendEvent($event, $data) {
    echo "event: $event\n";
    echo "data: $data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
?>


"The second code without the loop catches the session change." - but in that case the session change has already happened before this code runs - so those two aren't really comparable.

It's the same old story: session_start() must be used before any output. You use it again and again in the loop after you output stuff.

Instead of relying on the session in the loop you could get some session information when you start the script and then use information from the database in the loop. Assuming you're using a database. If not, use a file.

Tried getting the session var before the while loop but still the same issue. Thinking it can be due to the SSE concept itself, which I obviously don't fully understand yet.

"Tried getting the session var before the while loop but still the same issue." - but then it would be practically identical in that regard, to your second version - so how could that be?

You are using the default files session storage handler, yes? Then you could try and read the session file yourself, using file_get_contents (and then unserialize the value.) Not sure if the locking mechanism affects the session functions only though - it might be, that file_get_contents could not read the file, when another script currently has a lock on it. session_start has the "waiting" for the lock to be released already built-in - here you'd have to take care of that (or some appropriate error handling at least) yourself then.

Maybe switching to database session storage would be a good idea though.

@KIKOSoftware technically, the "must be used before any output" is only in regard to the session cookie it will try to set, but since only read access to the session data is necessary here, I wonder if it would work if the warning this will cause, was simply suppressed? (Interestingly enough though, session_start(['use_cookies' => false]); still throws the same warning - so I'm guessing the implementation might not differentiate between those two scenarios?)

@C3roe Yes, setting the cookie is real the reason for the restriction. But there must be more to it. Kevin isn't complaining about a warning but about the session content not reflecting any updates. I don't know enough about how PHP handles sessions to suggest a solution while still using them.

Appreciate all your input, sounds like a database solution is better.

I don't think calling session_start after output is an issue here, it would only be an issue if a session wasn't already setup and in your cookies. And as long as your not destroying the session anywhere, you should be able to do what you are trying to do.
You are better off using the database for data instead of the session, I've worked projects where the session gets very easily corrupted due to constantly adding/editing the session - it is just not really cut out for heavy exercises.
It is so easy for 2 scripts to clash if they are both accessing a session and trying to write to it at the same time, a database is literally perfect for storing, fetching and constantly modifying data. So use what is built for the task and forget trying to use sessions.
